# Jira Comment export html

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I have a problem with the comment Export...
I used this to put the comments into a Hashmap and put them into my vm which schould render them on html

```
issueParams.put("comments", ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager().getComments(issue));
```

the problem now is that there is the variable $comments and there are my comments but I can't get their content. It shows me in my foreach that there are two comments in my variable but i can't get for example the body ore the author with $comment.getBody...

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getComments() method returns a list of Comment object. You need to call getBody()

```
#foreach ($comment in $comments)
    $comment.body <br>
#end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it was just a syntax error cause I used $comment.getBody instead of $comment.body

Comment: if you want to use getBody, it should be "getBody()"